# ShaderLab use default unity skybox

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, skybox, shaderlab

All of the reflection examles set the Cubemaps with the property like:

```
Properties {
  _Cube("Reflection Map", Cube) = "" {}
}
```

But i want to use the skybox from "Lighting" for all shaders.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **unity_SpecCube0**, here's a simple version of the sampling with unity's helper functions

```
half3 GetCube(half3 _vector, half _smoothness) {
   half mip = _smoothness * 6.0;
   half4 rgbm = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEXCUBE_LOD(unity_SpecCube0, _vector, mip);
   return DecodeHDR(rgbm, unity_SpecCube0_HDR);
}
```